# Testing custom JsonDeserializer in Jackson / SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, json-deserialization

I am trying to write a unit test to a custom deserializer that is instantiated using a constructor with an @Autowired parameter and my entity marked with @JsonDeserialize. It works fine in my integration tests where a MockMvc brings up spring serverside.

However with tests where objectMapper.readValue(...) is being called, a new instance of deserializer using default constructor with no parameters is instantiated. Even though

```
@Bean
public MyDeserializer deserializer(ExternalObject externalObject)
```

instantiates wired version of deserializer, real call is still passed to empty constructor and context is not being filled up.

I tried manually instantiating of a deserializer instance and registering it in ObjectMapper, but it only works if I remove  @JsonDeserialize from my entity class (and it breaks my integration tests even if I do the same in my @Configuration class.) - looks related to this: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1300

I can still test the deserializer behavior calling deserializer.deserialize(...) directly, but this approach doesn't work for me in tests that are not Deserializer's unit tests...

UPD: working code below

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JacksonInject;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.HandlerInstantiator;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.Json;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.json.JsonTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;

import java.io.IOException;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

@JsonTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class JacksonInjectExample {
    private static final String JSON = "{\"field1\":\"value1\", \"field2\":123}";

    public static class ExternalObject {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MyExternalObject";
        }
    }

    @JsonDeserialize(using = MyDeserializer.class)
    public static class MyEntity {
        public String field1;
        public String field2;
        public String name;

        public MyEntity(ExternalObject eo) {
            name = eo.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    @Component
    public static class MyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyEntity> {

        @Autowired
        private ExternalObject external;

        public MyDeserializer() {
            SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
        }

        public MyDeserializer(@JacksonInject final ExternalObject external) {
            this.external = external;
        }

        @Override
        public MyEntity deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
            return new MyEntity(external);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public ExternalObject externalObject() {
            return new ExternalObject();
        }

        @Bean
        public MyDeserializer deserializer(ExternalObject externalObject) {
            return new MyDeserializer(externalObject);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void main() throws IOException {
        HandlerInstantiator hi = mock(HandlerInstantiator.class);
        MyDeserializer deserializer = new MyDeserializer();
        deserializer.external = new ExternalObject();
        doReturn(deserializer).when(hi).deserializerInstance(any(), any(), eq(MyDeserializer.class));
        final ObjectMapper mapper = Json.getObjectMapper();
        mapper.setHandlerInstantiator(hi);

        final MyEntity entity = mapper.readValue(JSON, MyEntity.class);
        Assert.assertEquals("MyExternalObject", entity.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting question, it made me wonder how autowiring into jackson deserializers actually works in a spring application. The jackson facility that is used seems to be the [`HandlerInstantiator` interface](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/HandlerInstantiator.java), which is [configured by spring to the `SpringHandlerInstantiator` implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java#L712), which just looks up the class in the application context.

So in theory you could setup an `ObjectMapper` in your unit test with your own (mocked) `HandlerInstantiator`, returning a prepared instance from `deserializerInstance()`. It seems to be fine to return `null` for other methods or when the class parameter does not match, this will cause jackson to create the instance on its own.

However, I do not think this is a good way to unit test deserialization logic, as the `ObjectMapper` setup is necessarily different from what is used during actual application execution. Using the [`JsonTest` annotation as suggested in Anton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60119522/139595) would be a much better approach, as you are getting the same json configuration that would be used during runtime.

Comment: I went ahead of myself awarding you the bounty :) It doesn't work, unfortunately. I have updated the question with the code utilizing your solutions. For some reason, ObjectMapper still tries to instantiate an instance of MyDeserializer with no args constructor, and since there's no context to wire up the ExternalObject, I get warning and subsequent NPE.

Comment: I had a look and it might just be small mistake, try `eq(MyDeserializer.class)` instead of `eq(MyEntity.class)`. Jackson already knows that it has to look for an instance of `MyDeserializer` from the annotations, the `HandlerInstantiator` just provides a corresponding instance, it is not responsible for finding the correct deserializer for a given entity class.

Comment: Thanks, it works now in this simplified example! Now I've got to figure why this is not working in my actual tests... Possibly because CollectionType deserializer is instantiated first and it creates MyDeserializer instance within it bypassing mocked instantiator...

Comment: Figured it, it was another instance of ObjectMapper. This method works perfectly without any use of reflection api and other ugly hacks. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to set this particularly using Jackson injection, but you can test it using spring Json tests. I think this method is closer to the real scenario and much more simplier. Spring will load only related to serialization/deserialization beans, thus you have to provide only custom beans or mocks instead them.

```
@JsonTest
public class JacksonInjectExample {

  private static final String JSON = "{\"field1\":\"value1\", \"field2\":123}";

  @Autowired
  private JacksonTester<MyEntity> jacksonTester;

  @Configuration
  public static class TestConfiguration {
      @Bean
      public ExternalObject externalObject() {
          return new ExternalObject();
      }
  }

  @Test
  public void test() throws IOException {
      MyEntity result = jacksonTester.parseObject(JSON);
      assertThat(result.getName()).isEqualTo("MyExternalObject");
  }
```

If you would like to use mocks use following snippet:

```
  @MockBean
  private ExternalObject externalObject;

  @Test
  public void test() throws IOException {
      when(externalObject.toString()).thenReturn("Any string");
      MyEntity result = jacksonTester.parseObject(JSON);
      assertThat(result.getName()).isEqualTo("Any string");
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, your code works, however it is essential to me to make parsing happen with evaluation of mapper.readValue(JSON, MyEntity.class) since I have tests that do it under the hood...

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests should not depend upon or invoke other major classes or frameworks. This is especially true if there are also integration or acceptance tests covering the functioning of the application with a particular set of dependencies as you describe. So it would be best to write the unit test so that it has a single class as its subject i.e. calling deserializer.deserialize(...) directly.

In this case a unit test should consist of instanciating a MyDeserializer with a mocked or stubbed ExternalObject, then testing that its deserialize() method returns a MyEntity correctly for different states of the JsonParser and DeserializationContext arguments. [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) is really good for setting up mock dependencies!

By using an ObjectMapper in the unit test, quite a lot of code from the Jackson framework is also being invoked in each run - so the test is not verifying the contract of MyDeserializer, it is verifying the behaviour of the combination of MyDeserializer and a particular release of Jackson. If there is a failure of the test it won't be immediatly clear which of all the components involved is at fault. And because setting up the environment of the two frameworks together is more difficult the test will prove brittle over time and fail more often due to issues with the setup in the test class.

The Jackson framework is responsible for writing unit tests of ObjectMapper.readValue and constructors using @JacksonInject. For the 'other unit tests that are not Deserializer's unit tests' - it would be best to mock/stub the MyDeserializer (or other dependencies) for that test. That way the other class's logic is being isolated from the logic in MyDeserializer - and the other class's contracts can be verified without being qualified by the behaviour of code outside of the unit under test.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I understand that calling it from ObjectMapper makes it not-quite-unit-test approach and for testing the deserializer itself it's sufficient, however, other tests where I am testing certain services unfortunately are tightly coupled to deserializer's result and mocking it would to a certain extend mean rewriting its complete logic in the test. I am aware that it is not a good design, but it is out of my hands right now, and in order to start refactoring I need to support existing tests the way they are.